Assign Random Colors in R
I have this code in R for simulating a country with different neighborhoods:
library(igraph)

width <- 30
height <- 20
num_nodes <- width * height

x <- rep(1:width, each = height)
y <- rep(1:height, times = width)

g <- make_empty_graph(n = num_nodes, directed = FALSE)

get_node_index <- function(i, j) (i - 1) * height + j

# Add edges
edges <- c()
for(i in 1:width) {
  for(j in 1:height) {
    current_node <- get_node_index(i, j)
    if(i < width) edges <- c(edges, current_node, get_node_index(i + 1, j))
    if(j < height) edges <- c(edges, current_node, get_node_index(i, j + 1))
  }
}
g <- add_edges(g, edges)

V(g)$x <- x
V(g)$y <- y

V(g)$color <- sample(c("red", "blue"), num_nodes, replace = TRUE)

count_patches <- function(color) {
  subgraph <- induced_subgraph(g, V(g)[V(g)$color == color])
  components <- components(subgraph)
  return(components$no)
}

plot(g, layout = cbind(V(g)$x, V(g)$y), 
     vertex.size = 7,  
     vertex.label = NA,
     edge.arrow.size = 0.5,
     edge.color = "lightgray"
     )


However, this is just assigning random colors to each node.
I am trying to make the colors more in "clusters" to resemble a more natural pattern like  this:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Texas_gubernatorial_election_maps#/media/File:TXGov1990Map.png
Can this be done in R?

A second attempt:
library(igraph)

width <- 30
height <- 20
num_nodes <- width * height

x <- rep(1:width, each = height)
y <- rep(1:height, times = width)

g <- make_empty_graph(n = num_nodes, directed = FALSE)

#  get node index
get_node_index <- function(i, j) (i - 1) * height + j

# add edges
edges <- c()
for(i in 1:width) {
    for(j in 1:height) {
        current_node <- get_node_index(i, j)
        # Connect to right neighbor
        if(i < width) edges <- c(edges, current_node, get_node_index(i + 1, j))
        # Connect to bottom neighbor
        if(j < height) edges <- c(edges, current_node, get_node_index(i, j + 1))
    }
}
g <- add_edges(g, edges)

# set node positions
V(g)$x <- x
V(g)$y <- y

# initialize all nodes as white
V(g)$color <- "white"

#  get neighbors
get_neighbors <- function(node) {
    neighbors(g, node)
}

#define seeds
num_seeds <- 50
red_seeds <- sample(V(g), num_seeds)
blue_seeds <- sample(setdiff(V(g), red_seeds), num_seeds)

# color the seed nodes
V(g)[red_seeds]$color <- "red"
V(g)[blue_seeds]$color <- "blue"

#  initial probability for color spreading
base_spread_probability <- 0.2

# diffusion process
while(any(V(g)$color == "white")) {
    red_front <- V(g)[V(g)$color == "red"]
    blue_front <- V(g)[V(g)$color == "blue"]
    
    new_red <- unique(unlist(sapply(red_front, get_neighbors)))
    new_blue <- unique(unlist(sapply(blue_front, get_neighbors)))
    
    # color new nodes with probability, but don't overwrite existing colors
    for (node in new_red[V(g)[new_red]$color == "white"]) {
        if (runif(1) < base_spread_probability * (1 + runif(1, -0.5, 0.5))) {
            V(g)[node]$color <- "red"
        }
    }
    
    for (node in new_blue[V(g)[new_blue]$color == "white"]) {
        if (runif(1) < base_spread_probability * (1 + runif(1, -0.5, 0.5))) {
            V(g)[node]$color <- "blue"
        }
    }
    
    # If no new nodes were colored, increase probability to ensure completion
    if(all(V(g)[new_red]$color != "red" & V(g)[new_blue]$color != "blue")) {
        base_spread_probability <- min(1, base_spread_probability + 0.05)
    }
}


plot(g, layout = cbind(V(g)$x, V(g)$y), 
     vertex.size = 7, 
     vertex.label = NA, 
     edge.arrow.size = 0.5)



Check out the spatstat package for spatial statistics. It has many ways to sample things that are spatially clustered. Or roll your own, pick a few points as random starts, and then build an iterative process where each uncolored point with colored neighbors is assigned a color with a probability based on it's adjacency. Or define a continuous function over the region and define colors based on that function's value with added noise...

could you please show me an example if you have time?

Would red and blue need to show up an even 50/50?

@jpsmith: any proportion is ok ...

One low-effort option is to apply a smoothing kernel on a matrix / raster representation of numerical grid values, for this we can use terra::focal().
As a first step, we'll build a SpatRaster for terra from graph's vertex table (x, y , color), we can then use focal(fun = "mean", ...), which by default uses 3x3 moving window to calculate mean values for each cell. By thresholding / binning mean values we can get back to categoricals, like colors.
To tweak resulting patterns, focal() can be applied multiple times and threshold value can be adjusted.  We can also change probability vector in sample() to change red / blue ratio of input data.
library(igraph)
library(terra)

width <- 30
height <- 20
num_nodes <- width * height

x <- rep(1:width, each = height)
y <- rep(1:height, times = width)
g <- make_lattice(c(height,width))
V(g)$x <- x
V(g)$y <- y

set.seed(42)
V(g)$color <- sample(c("red", "blue"), num_nodes, replace = TRUE)

# helper function to apply mean filter (smoothing 3x3 kernel) to terra SpatRaster r, 
# repeat n times
mean_n <- \(r, n) Reduce(\(x, ...) focal(x, fun = "mean", na.rm = TRUE, expand = TRUE), x = seq_len(n), init = r)

V(g)$color <- 
  as_data_frame(g, "vertices") |> 
  # recode colors to numericals
  within(color <- c("red" = 0, "blue" = 1)[color]) |> 
  # vertex frame (x, y, numerical color) to SpatRaster
  rast() |>
  # apply focal(r, fun = "mean") twice
  mean_n(2) |> 
  # use .5 threshold value to categorize back to "red" & "blue";
  # from factor to character for plotting
  as.matrix(wide = TRUE) |> 
  cut(breaks = c(-Inf, .5, Inf), labels = c("red","blue")) |> 
  as.character() 

withr::with_par(
  list(mar = c(0,0,0,0)),
  plot(g, layout = cbind(V(g)$x, V(g)$y), 
       vertex.size = 7,  
       vertex.label = NA,
       edge.arrow.size = 0.5,
       edge.color = "lightgray"
       )
)


Though if you can parametrize your clusters and/or are after more controlled output, you definitely should look into spatstat.

thanks @margusl! I tried to do this using a different method over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78949381/how-to-tell-if-a-point-has-been-colored-twice-in-r

It's not totally clear what you're trying to accomplish so I'm not sure if this helps, but here's a really crude solution that randomly assigns the color in clusters to the graph in your example.
library(igraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'igraph'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     decompose, spectrum
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     union

width <- 30
height <- 20
num_nodes <- width * height

x <- rep(1:width, each = height)
y <- rep(1:height, times = width)

g <- make_empty_graph(n = num_nodes, directed = FALSE)

get_node_index <- function(i, j) (i - 1) * height + j

# Add edges
edges <- c()
for(i in 1:width) {
  for(j in 1:height) {
    current_node <- get_node_index(i, j)
    if(i < width) edges <- c(edges, current_node, get_node_index(i + 1, j))
    if(j < height) edges <- c(edges, current_node, get_node_index(i, j + 1))
  }
}
g <- add_edges(g, edges)

V(g)$x <- x
V(g)$y <- y

colors <- NULL
i <- 1
while(i <= num_nodes){
  # Set a size for the cluster randomly
  cluster_size <- sample(seq(5, 50), 1)
  # Set the color for the cluster randomly
  cluster_color <- sample(c("red", "blue"), 1, replace = TRUE)
  # Assign the cluster color for each node in the cluster or as many that remain in the graph
  if((i + cluster_size - 1) <= num_nodes){
    cluster_colors <- sample(cluster_color, cluster_size, replace = TRUE)
  } else {
    cluster_colors <- sample(cluster_color, num_nodes - i + 1, replace = TRUE)
  }
  colors <- append(colors, cluster_colors)
  i <- i + cluster_size
}
V(g)$color <- colors

count_patches <- function(color) {
  subgraph <- induced_subgraph(g, V(g)[V(g)$color == color])
  components <- components(subgraph)
  return(components$no)
}

plot(g, layout = cbind(V(g)$x, V(g)$y), 
     vertex.size = 7,  
     vertex.label = NA,
     edge.arrow.size = 0.5,
     edge.color = "lightgray"
)


Created on 2024-09-04 with reprex v2.1.1

thank you so much! is it possible to make the the patterns more "patchy"? e.g. islands of red and blue to resemble counties in a state?

This is an interesting question and I am sure there are multiple ways to approach this. One way would be to create a function that randomly creates n cluster "seeds" (nclust), expands them to a given size (clustsize) and then randomly censors them uniformly to create a "patchiness" (censoring):
set.seed(123)
clust_fun <- function(v_g, 
                      nclust = 10, 
                      clustsize = 20, 
                      censoring = 0.1){
  clust_seed <- sort(sample(length(v_g), nclust))
  xx <- unique(unlist(purrr::map2(clust_seed - (clustsize / 2), clust_seed + (clustsize / 2), seq)))
  xx[runif(length(xx)) <= (1 - censoring) & xx > 0 & xx < length(v_g)]
}

nn <- length(V(g))
V(g)$color <- rep("blue", nn)
V(g)$color[clust_fun(v_g = V(g))] <- "red"

plot(g, layout = cbind(V(g)$x, V(g)$y), 
     vertex.size = 7,  
     vertex.label = NA,
     edge.arrow.size = 0.5,
     edge.color = "lightgray"
)

Here I've defaulted to a 10 seeds with a max cluster size of 20 with only light "patchiness" (10%). You can play around to make them more accurate to what you are envisioning.

