How to tell if a point has been colored twice in R?
This is a follow-up question from my previous question Assign Random Colors in R
(After much trial and error) I wrote this function which randomly colors some nodes on a network and colors 3 of their neighbors with the same color (notice the coloring scale - dark  color for the original node, light color for the neighbors).
library(igraph)
library(colorspace)


create_colored_network <- function(width, height, colors, source_nodes, neighbor_degree = 3) {
    num_nodes <- width * height
    
    # Create a grid
    x <- rep(1:width, each = height)
    y <- rep(1:height, times = width)
    
    g <- make_empty_graph(n = num_nodes, directed = FALSE)
    
    # Function to get node index
    get_node_index <- function(i, j) (i - 1) * height + j
    
    # Add edges
    edges <- c()
    for(i in 1:width) {
        for(j in 1:height) {
            current_node <- get_node_index(i, j)
            
            # Connect to right neighbor
            if(i < width) edges <- c(edges, current_node, get_node_index(i + 1, j))
            
            # Connect to bottom neighbor
            if(j < height) edges <- c(edges, current_node, get_node_index(i, j + 1))
        }
    }
    
    g <- add_edges(g, edges)
    
    V(g)$x <- x
    V(g)$y <- y
    
    # Select random nodes and color them
    all_nodes <- 1:num_nodes
    V(g)$color <- "white"
    
    for (i in 1:length(colors)) {
        available_nodes <- all_nodes[!all_nodes %in% unlist(sapply(colors[1:i-1], function(c) V(g)[color == c]))]
        source <- sample(available_nodes, source_nodes[i])
        V(g)[source]$color <- colors[i]
        
        # Color neighbors
        neighbors <- unique(unlist(neighborhood(g, order = neighbor_degree, nodes = source)))
        neighbor_color <- lighten(colors[i], amount = 0.7)  # Create a lighter version of the color
        V(g)[neighbors]$color <- ifelse(V(g)[neighbors]$color == "white", neighbor_color, V(g)[neighbors]$color)
    }
    
    plot(g, vertex.size = 7, vertex.label = NA, main = "Colored Network")
    
    
    legend_colors <- c(colors, sapply(colors, function(c) lighten(c, amount = 0.7)), "white")
    legend_labels <- c(paste(capitalize(colors), "nodes"), 
                       paste(capitalize(colors), "neighbors"), 
                       "Other nodes")
    
    legend("bottom", 
           legend = legend_labels,
           col = legend_colors, 
           pch = 19, 
           pt.cex = 1.5, 
           cex = 0.8, 
           bty = "n", 
           horiz = TRUE)
}

capitalize <- function(x) {
    paste0(toupper(substr(x, 1, 1)), substr(x, 2, nchar(x)))
}

Here is how to call this function:
width <- 30
height <- 20
colors <- c("red", "blue", "green", "purple")
source_nodes <- c(2, 2, 3, 9)

create_colored_network(width, height, colors, source_nodes)


I am trying to make the following changes to this:

There is a lot of white space on the network. I was trying to get the colors to "diffuse" more across the network by trying different numbers of node numbers. I thought I could just color all the white nodes a different color ... but is there some approach I can take to make sure the diffusion colors all nodes?

Intersections are guaranteed to happen (depends on which color expands first), e.g.



Is it possible to track which nodes have been colored over by multiple colors?
Much appreciated ...

What's the meaning of the source_nodes parameter? I'm trying to modify your function, but I don't understand its role.
Also, not at all an answer to your question but you may be interested in the tidygraph library. It provides some simple to use clustering algorithms beyond what igraph provides and it's interface is pretty simple to learn. https://tidygraph.data-imaginist.com/reference/index.html#node-measures

You could always keep a vector or table containing the coordinates of each point when you color it, then some simple filtering will return coordinate values which occur more than once.   Or, of course, just remove a point from the "input" set once it's been colored.

This might not be quite what you asked, instead of traversing through graph and tracking / updating node attributes it aims to partition all nodes into clusters.
Voronoi diagram is often used for such task and it's also available in igraph through voronoi_cells(). Usability of resulting clusters probably depends on your actual use case, though a bit smarter approach for sampling source node locations should provide finer control over resulting cluster distribution (perhaps spatstat.random::runifpoint() for uniform distribution, or   spatstat.random::rstrat() to generate spatially stratified point locations) .
library(igraph, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# width, height - lattice dimensions
# colors        - character vector of colors
# source_nodes  - number of source nodes for each color in `colors`
# tiebreaker    - what to do when a vertex is at the same distance from multiple generators
#                 ("random", "first", "last")
create_colored_network <- function(width, height, colors, source_nodes, tiebreaker = "random") {
  # create lattice graph 
  g <- make_lattice(dimvector = c(height,width))
  V(g)$x <- rep(seq_len(width),  each  = height) 
  V(g)$y <- rep(seq_len(height), times = width)
  
  # generate a shuffled vector of source nodes, colors as names
  # Named num [1:16] 375 101 229 490 199 132 586 36 571 178 ...
  # - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:16] "green" "purple" "red" "blue" ...
  
  # sample from graph vertex sequnece
  # source_idx <- 
  #   sample(vcount(g), sum(source_nodes)) |> 
  #   setNames(rep(colors, source_nodes) |> sample())
  
  # sample through x-y coordinates
  source_idx <- 
    # sample x & w coordinates for source nodes
    sapply(list(width, height), sample, sum(source_nodes)) |> 
    # calculate node inidices from sampled coordinates
    apply(MARGIN = 1, \(xy, h) (xy[1] - 1) * h + xy[2], h = height) |> 
    # shuffle colors, affects tiebreaking in voronoi_cells    
    setNames(rep(colors, source_nodes) |> sample())
  

  # use Voronoi partitioning to cluster all network nodes by source_idx nodes,
  # clu$membership includes source node sequence number (0-based)
  clu <- voronoi_cells(g, source_idx, tiebreaker = tiebreaker)
  
  # set all node colors to lightened varaiants of colors from source_idx names
  V(g)$color <- 
    # sequence numbers are 0-based
    source_idx[clu$membership + 1] |> 
    names() |> 
    colorspace::lighten(amount = 0.7)
  
  # override source node colors  
  V(g)$color[source_idx] <- names(source_idx)
  
  # store source node flag and cluster id in vertex attributes
  V(g)$is_source  <- FALSE
  V(g)$is_source[source_idx] <- TRUE
  V(g)$membership <- clu$membership
  
  # return graph
  g
}

set.seed(42)
g <- create_colored_network(
  width = 30, height = 20, 
  colors = c("red", "blue", "green", "purple"), 
  source_nodes = c(2, 2, 3, 9),
  tiebreaker = "first")

withr::with_par(
  list(mar = c(0,0,0,0)),
  plot(g, layout = cbind(V(g)$x, V(g)$y), 
       vertex.size = 7,  
       vertex.label = V(g)$membership,
       vertex.label.cex = .75,
       vertex.frame.color = V(g)$membership,
       vertex.frame.width = .5,
       edge.arrow.size = 0.5,
       edge.color = "lightgray")
)



You might also want test with other tiebreaker values of voronoi_cells(), default is "random", which is more likely to result with some scattered nodes surrounded by another cluster. Here are all 3 options, ("random", "first", "last"):
withr::with_par(
  list(mfrow = c(1, 3), mar = c(10,0,5,0)),
  lapply(c("random", "first", "last"), 
         \(tb) {
           set.seed(42)
           create_colored_network(width = 30, height = 20, 
                                        colors = c("red", "blue", "green", "purple"), 
                                        source_nodes = c(2, 2, 3, 9), tiebreaker = tb) |>
             plot(layout = cbind(V(g)$x, V(g)$y), vertex.size = 7,  
                  vertex.label = V(g)$membership, vertex.label.cex = .75,
                  vertex.frame.color = V(g)$membership, vertex.frame.width = .5,
                  edge.arrow.size = 0.5, edge.color = "lightgray",
                  main = paste0("tiebreaker = ", tb))
           }
         )
  )


Created on 2024-09-05 with reprex v2.1.1

WOW! Thank you so much!
